# Numbers between a and b without their permutations

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm

I've written a similar question which was closed I would like to ask **not the code** but an efficiency tip. I haven't coded but if I can't find any good hint in here I'll go and code straightforward. My question:

Suppose you have a function listNums that take **a** as lower bound and **b** as upper bound.

For example a=120 and b=400

I want to print numbers between these numbers with one rule. 120's permutations are 102,210,201 etc. Since I've got 120 I would like to skip printing 201 or 210.

**Reason:** The upper limit can go up to 10<sup>20</sup> and reducing the permutations would help the running time.

Again just asking for efficiency tips.

Comment: Do you have informations about the lower bound?

Comment: Should `222` be printed?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Lower bound can be anything from 1 to 10^20-1. As the Upper bound can be 1 to 10^20

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit as long as `222` wasn't printed

Comment: If x and y are your numbers and y is really high then it is very likely that the number of numbers you want to skip is very low compared to (y-x). Not sure how you can make it more efficient!

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Is that a "no"?

Comment: 222 should be printed,just like 22222, 222222 but talking for this example yes 222 should be printed

Comment: @ElKamina I think it would reduce a lot since 124 will reduce the numbers 214,241,142 and the number after it will cover numbers 152,215,251 etc.

Comment: If you have 120, do you also skip 2010 or 200001?  What if you have 122?  Do you skip 221 but not 21 and 2221?  Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: @kfmfe04 Thank you for the heads up. And yes you are right. if you have 120 also 2010 2001 etc. For 122 in this **particular** example you skip 221, 21 is not in the bounds and you cannot skip 2221 since it has an additional 2.

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219112/checking-whether-two-numbers-are-permutation-of-each-other

Comment: You can't **print** them with such an upper bound. You are probably not even supposed to count them one by one. - Nevermind if this is just for brute-forcing simple cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure how you are handling 0s (eg: after outputting 1 do you skip 10, 100 etc since  technically 1=01=001..).

The trick is to select a number such that all its digits are in increasing order (from left to right).

You can do it recursively. AT every recursion add a digit and make sure it is equal to or higher than the one you recently added.

EDIT: If the generated number is less than the lower limit then permute it in such a way that it is greater than or equal to the lower limit. If A1A2A3..Ak is your number and it is lower than limit), then incrementally check if any of A2A1A3...Ak, A3A1A2...Ak, ... , AkA1A2...Ak-1 are within limit. If need arises, repeat this step to with keeping Ak as first digit and finding a combination of A1A2..Ak-1.

Eg: Assume we are selecting 3 digits and lower limit is 99. If the combination is 012, then the lowest permutation that is higher than 99 is 102.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but here is one thing. Consider you've selected 99 as lower bound and 150 for the upper bound. Starting from 99,100 is unique,101,102,103,104 etc. So the increasing rule cannot be applied here

Comment: @rolandbishop If the number is lower than the limit, permute it.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thank you for your effort

Comment: Skip a number if its digits aren't in increasing order and the previous permutation of those digits is within the bounds. With a fixed number of digits the previous permutation should be constant time to compute.

Answer (score 0):

When the lower bound is 0, an answer is given by the set of numbers with non-decreasing digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 66, 67, 68, 69, 77, 78, 79, 88, 89, 99, 111, 112...) that fall in the requested range.

This sequence is easily formed by incrementing an integer, and when there is a carry, replicate the digit instead of carrying. Exemple: 73 is followed by 73+1 = 74 (no carry); 79 is followed by 79+1 = 80 (carry), so 88 instead; 22356999 is followed by 22356999+1 = 22357000, hence 22357777.

```
# Python code
A= 0 # CAUTION: this version only works for A == 0 !
B= 1000

N= A
while N < B:
    # Detect zeroes at the end
    S= str(N)
    P= S.find('0')

    if P > 0:
        # Replicate the last nonzero digit
        S= S[:P] + ((len(S) - P) * S[P-1])
        N= eval(S)

    # Next candidate
    print N
    N+= 1
```

Dealing with a nonzero lower bound is a lot more tricky.